# Can't access /ext/ref/dropoff on PingFederate v6.1

Tags: saml, pingfederate

I'm working on PingFederate v6 + Agentless-Integration-Kit-1-2. 
After I installed and run. When I tried to test AgentlessIntegrationKitSample then it has problem when IdP request data to /ext/ref/dropoff url.

Default user & password on configuration.jsp is idpuser & idppassword can't access the url.

What the default password of PingFederate? or What I have to config before run example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything that you need to know about running the sample apps in the AIK is in the [documentation](http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/AIK12/Sample+Applications).

As long as you have put data.zip into the drop-in deployer, deployed the sample apps, and configured them to use the certs as described in the doc via configuration.jsp, it works.

If you're asking what the default user/password of PingFederate is for the admin console, then it is administrator/2Federate .

Anything above that, though, and I'm going to need better information to help you.